# Is the variable/array on the PDO execute also prepared?

Tags: php

In the below, I would be speaking of $val1. Is $val1 also prepared?

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1=:var1 LIMIT 1";
 $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array(':var1'=>$val1));
```

Comment: no. it's not "prepared". it'll simply be stuffed into the query when it's actually executed, at the time it's executed.

Comment: So I would need to check $val1 myself for safety to avoid a sql injection?

Comment: no. that's why you're using prepared statements. the DB library will take care of any injection problems for you. If you were doing `$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE col1 = $val1"`, then yes, you'd have to escape yourself.

Comment: @MarcB You don't *have* to, but you still *should*. If not for protection against second-order injection, for basic data validation and integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is "prepared" (the way you put it) as well as any other placeholder-based value.
Otherwise there would be no sense in such syntax.